# OK to use OIDC ID token as bearer token from SPA to stateless C# backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect, bearer-token

I am developing SPAs in Angular and React.  I am connecting these SPAs to OIDC identity providers, using authorization code + PKCE.

Now, I need some way to communicate the user context to the backend APIs in C# (ASP.NET Core).

My problem is: the access tokens from my particular IDP are opaque.

If the access tokens were JWTs, I would use these as bearer tokens with something like

```
services.AddAuthentication("token")
.AddJwtBearer(...)
```

My question is, should I use the *ID token* as a JWT bearer token, to communicate authentication and user context?  The only claim I am interested in is the sub or email claims to identify the user.

Alternatively:

What is the appropriate ASP.NET configuration to use the userinfo or introspection endpoint to get the user profile (email etc.)?

And how to do that in a way that won't require a round trip on every request?

Comment: Can you follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#protocol-diagram-access-token-acquisition) pattern and use your ID token to request an JWT access token with the claims you want?

Comment: Which IDP are you using?

Comment: IDP is homegrown.

Answer (score 0):

You could let AddJwtBearer using its event handlers to query your IDP using the access token you got for the real user details. You should not use the ID-token as the life time of those are usually very short, like 5 minutes.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Perhaps this page can give you some hints? https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/apis/aspnetcore/reference/

Comment: I looked at this - it _almost_ works except that the token introspection endpoint does not return the 'email' claim.

Comment: Glad it almost works! Guess that is something you have to configure at the IDP? or are you not asking for the right scopes?

Comment: I see "email" in the requested scopes; so I think either the IDP doesn't return the email claim on the introspection endpoint (only 'active' is required)  What I really need is something like OAuth2Introspection that calls the userinfo endpoint instead of token introspection.

Comment: What about calling the UserInfo endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (?), you should not use the ID-Token in place of the Access-Token.  Most OP (OIDC Providers) allow for the return of an ID-Token along with the Access-Token when authenticating (/calling the 'authorize' endpoint); e.g. AAD (Azure AD) even.  Look into the config - that will allow for this.  I've found that most providers (for the 'Authorization Code' flow with PKCE included) do seem to support it (one way or the other).

Otherwise, just explicitly/actively call the (OIDC) 'userinfo' endpoint to obtain the identity information.

Comment: Calling userinfo endpoint with the access token works, but would rather not have to do this explicitly or on every request.  It would be reasonable if there were some automagic way to do with AddAuthentication similar to OAuth2Introspection.

Comment: 1) You should be able to have the ID Token returned with the Access Token; and 2) in most scenarios I don't see why you would need to keep checking for updates (upon the identity) - at least maybe go with what you might effectively think of as been 'eventual consistency' whereby you update your local cache/store of the information the next time you do call the endpoint.